# CGO: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'char *'

Tags: c, python-3.x, cgo

So I am trying to create a go function that adds a value to a c struct that I am in cgo.

```golang
package main

/*
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct {
    char *response;
} Resp;

typedef struct {
    char resp_out;
} Resp_Out;

void reponse_return(Resp r_in, Resp_Out r_out)
{
    r_out.resp_out = r_in.response;
}
*/
import "C"

//export getResponse
func getResponse() C.Resp {
    C.Resp{
        response: C.CString("Hello World),
    }
}
```

The getResponse function adds "Hello World" to the C struct. Now What I am trying to do in c is to create a c function where the Resp.response c struct value gives the value to Resp_Out.resp_out value. But I keep on getting this error when I am trying to compile this as a shared object.

```
duplicate symbol '_reponse_return' in:
    $WORK/b001/_x001.o
    $WORK/b001/_x002.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
# command-line-arguments
In file included from _cgo_export.c:4:
cgotest2.go:18:17: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'char *'; dereference with * [-Wint-conversion]
# command-line-arguments
./cgotest2.go:18:17: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'char *'; dereference with * [-Wint-conversion]
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: This assignment r_out.resp_out = r_in.response; does not make a sense. What is unclear? See the types of resp_out and response.

Comment: Sorry I don't know c that much but I am trying to add a value in the Resp c struct from cgo then adding that value to another c struct in a c function so that I can access it through python's ctypes in_dll function.